# Referring to arrays in a for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

Suppose i have 3 Numpy arrays containing floats with the following names: one two three.

Is it possible to refer to them in a for-loop in the following manner:

```
list=one two three

for arr in list:
    arr=arr[2,1]+1
```

The above example obviously does not work but i was wondering if there is a way to do this?

Comment: `arr` seems to be a 2-D array, `array[2,1]` is a float. What do you want to with this float exactly? Replace the whole array with one single value? Replace only the value at index `[2,1]`?

Comment: Hi. I would like to replace the value at index [2,1].

Comment: There are two issues - how to iterate of a list or tuple of arrays (or any kind of object), and how to make changes one of those objects.  `arr=...`  does not change `arr` in-place.  It reassigns the variable `arr`.

Comment: Yes that is what i want really. @EricDuminil answer was a first step but I was hoping this simple example could be generalized to a more complex case. Apparently it does not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify where you'd like to save the value:

```
arr[2,1] = arr[2,1] + 1
```

or just:

```
arr[2,1] += 1
```

So the whole code becomes:

```
import numpy as np
one = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2)
two = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2)
arrays = [one, two]
for arr in arrays:
    arr[2, 1] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work if you made your list variable a list:

```
list=[one, two, three]
for arr in list:
    arr=arr[2,1]+1
```

Comment: I tried that and it does not make any changes to the array unfortunately.