# Iterating over a list of arrays while making changes to each array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

This is a follow-up post from a previous question of mine: [Referring to arrays in a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058472/referring-to-arrays-in-a-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment85123191_49058472).

I would like to generalize the solution proposed there in order to be able to complete more complex tasks, such as attaching a column to each array that contains the result of some calculation:

```
import numpy as np
list=[one, two, three]

for arr in list:
    arr=np.column_stack([arr,5*arr[:,2]-arr[:,1])])
```

All three arrays have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [59]: one=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [60]: two=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
```

Forget about the loop for the moment, and just try to change `one`:

```
In [61]: arr = one
In [62]: arr=np.column_stack([arr,5*arr[:,2]-arr[:,1]])
In [63]: arr
Out[63]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  9],
       [ 3,  4,  5, 21]])
In [65]: one
Out[65]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

This action has changed `arr`, but not `one`.  Originally `arr` referenced the same object (`ndarray`) as `one`, but after the new assignment, it referenced a new array.

In

```
for arr in alist:
    arr = ....
```

`arr` is assigned an element of `alist`.  But then in the loop it is assigned another something else, without changing the original object.  On the next iteration, `arr` is assigned the next element in the list, and so on.

You need to keep in mind several things.

- how Python assigns values to variables
- how Python assigns values to an iteration variable
- what functions like `column_stack` to

In your previous question

```
In [69]: for arg in [one,two]:
    ...:     arg[:,1:] += 10
    ...:     
In [70]: one
Out[70]: 
array([[ 0, 11, 12],
       [ 3, 14, 15]])
In [71]: two
Out[71]: 
array([[ 0, 11, 12],
       [ 3, 14, 15]])
```

this works because the `arg[:,1:] += 10` is modifying the array currently assigned to `arg`.  An array is `mutable`; element values can be changed in-place.

`np.column_stack()` does not act in-place.  It makes new array.

About the only way that you can change `one` and `two` with a list is a sequence of operations like:

```
In [72]: newlist=[np.column_stack([arr,5*arr[:,2]-arr[:,1]]) for arg in [one,two]]
In [73]: newlist
Out[73]: 
[array([[ 0,  1,  2,  9,  9],
        [ 3,  4,  5, 21, 21]]), array([[ 0,  1,  2,  9,  9],
        [ 3,  4,  5, 21, 21]])]
In [74]: one
Out[74]: 
array([[ 0, 11, 12],
       [ 3, 14, 15]])
In [75]: one, two = newlist
In [76]: one
Out[76]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  9,  9],
       [ 3,  4,  5, 21, 21]])
```

`In[72]` creates a new list, with new arrays. `In[75]` assigns these new arrays to the variables `one` and `two`.  This wipes out their previous references.  In effect I did `one=[np.column_stack([one,5*one[:,2]-one[:,1]])`, and similarly for `two`.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to the variable doesn't update the list, it's just a temporary reference to the value that's in the array.

Use `enumerate` to get the list index, then you can replace it with the result.

```
for index, arr in enumerate(myList):
    myList[index] = np.column_stack([arr,5*arr[:,2]-arr[:,1])])
```

Also, avoid using the names of built-in classes and functions as your own variable names. `list` is a standard class.

Comment: Thank you but this does not work unfortunately. Nothing is replaced in the arrays.

Comment: Are you expecting it to modify the variables `one`, `two`, `three` as well?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to attach the column with the calculation results to each of the three arrays.

Comment: Using a variable just returns a reference to the value it contains, it doesn't return a reference to the variable itself. You can't change the variable's value through an array that was built from it. But if the variable contains mutable data, you can mutate that object.

Comment: That has to be done using methods of the object itself, not assignments to the variables that refer to it.

Comment: Like `someList.append()` will modify a list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the solution you are referencing can only be generalized to in-place changes to the array. Anything that changes the size will AFAIK create a new array.

So this

```
>>> X,Y,Z = (np.arange(i+1, i+10, dtype=float).reshape(3, 3) for i in range(3))
>>> L = [X,Y,Z]
>>> for arr in L:
...    np.sin(arr, out=arr)
```

or this

```
>>> for arr in L:
...     arr[1] = arr[1, ::-1]
```

will work.

You can even replace the entire array, as long as you do it in-place:

```
>>> for arr in L:
...     arr[...] = 1.7
```

But this

```
>>> for arr in L:
...    np.append(arr, arr[-1])
```

will not change the original arrays but create new ones. Assigning back to `arr` won't help because it just rebinds the name `arr` to the new object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that in Python, variables are references to values. The iteration variable is a variable, so assigning a new value to this variable do not change the iterable.

In this case, why not use lists comprehensions ?

```
import numpy as np
my_list = [one, two, three]

my_list = [np.column_stack([arr,5*arr[:,2]-arr[:,1])]) for arr in list]
```

And please, don't shadow `list`type…